# Смещение элементов RecyclerView при удалении

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток.
Использую RecyclerView для создания горизонтального списка.
Выделяю элементы, к примеру : 1-й и 3-й, потом удаляю 1-й и выделение сдвигается с 1-го на 2-й и с 3-го на 4-й соответственно.
Помогите решить данную проблему, уже голову сломал.

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {
private List<ContactInfo> contactList;
private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedPositions = new SparseBooleanArray(50);
public ContactAdapter(List<ContactInfo> contactList) {

    this.contactList = contactList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return contactList.size();
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int position) {
    ContactInfo ci = contactList.get(position);

    contactViewHolder.vName.setText(ci.name);
    contactViewHolder.vSurname.setText(ci.surname);

    contactViewHolder.setItem(mSelectedPositions.get(position));
    //contactViewHolder.butto.setText(ci.name);
    //contactViewHolder.vEmail.setText(ci.email);
    //contactViewHolder.vTitle.setText(ci.name);
}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);

    return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);

}

public  class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener  {

    protected TextView vName;
    protected TextView vSurname;
    protected Button butto;

    public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        vName =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        vSurname = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.days);
        butto = (Button)  v.findViewById(R.id.but);

        //vEmail = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
       // vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);

        butto.setOnClickListener(this);
        butto.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(butto)) {
            if( mSelectedPositions.get(getAdapterPosition())) {
                butto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_y);
            }
            else {
                butto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.inactive_y);
            }
           changestate(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(butto)) {
            removeAt(getAdapterPosition());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void changestate(int position) {

        boolean state;
        state = mSelectedPositions.get(position);
        state = !state;
        mSelectedPositions.put(position, state);
        notifyItemChanged(position);

    }

    public void removeAt(int position) {
        contactList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), contactList.size());
    }

    public void setItem(boolean station) {
        if( station) {
            butto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_y);
        }
        else {
            butto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.inactive_y);
        }
        mSelectedPositions.put(getAdapterPosition(), station);
    }
}}
```

Comment: В массиве `mSelectedPositions` тоже надо состояния менять в соответствии с удалением элементов. Сейчас там у вас при удалении хранится информация та же, что и до удаления

Comment: добавил это. теперь удаленный элемент теряет выделение , но остальные все так же смещаются...

Comment: У ContactInfo есть уникальный ID? Если найдется, то упростит задачу кардинально. `setBackgroundResource()` лучше перенести в `onBindViewHolder()` и дёргать его вызовом `notifyItemChanged()`

Comment: Можно ли по-подробней как мне поможет наличие ID ?

Comment: @Vanodga, в mSelectedPositions хранить не позиции, а ID всех выделенных элементов. Отпадет необходимость заботиться о сдвигах.

Comment: @Vanodga, если делаете contextual action mode, то посмотрите на статью [RecyclerView Part 2: Choice Modes](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-2-choice-modes/) и особенно на тамошний пример на гитхабе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что массивы основного списка `contactList`и вспомогательного, с отметками о выделении, `mSelectedPositions` не синхронизированы. При удалении или добавлении элементов в основной список их позиции сдвигаются, в вспомогательном же все находится на прежних местах и индексы теперь не соответствуют данным:

До удаления:

```
contact | select
----------------
item1   | true
item2   | false
item3   | false
item4   | true
```

После удаления второго элемента:

```
contact | select
----------------
item1   | true
item3   | false
item4   | false
        | true
```

Как видите, все сдвигается. Чтобы этого не происходило, в вспомогательном списке нужно так же удалять элемент с той же позицией, чтобы индексы позиций и содержимое в основном и вспомогательном списке соответствовали друг другу:

```
public void removeAt(int position) {
        contactList.remove(position);
        mSelectedPositions.delete(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), contactList.size());
```

Аналогично, и при добавлении элемента в основной список, нужно в ту же позицию добавлять и элемент в вспомогательный список. Вообще, действия с основным и вспомогательным списком должны быть зеркальными.

Comment: к сожалению ` mSelectedPositions.delete(position);` не удаляет ячейку массива со сдвигом , на сколько я понял на практике

Comment: Кстати, да, не обратил сразу внимание. Сдвигать то он сдвигает, здесь проблема в том, что `SparseArray` по сути `Map`, то есть коллекция ключ-значение. Здесь аргументы не позиции, а ключи - они не изменяются при удалении элементов.Можно использовать что то вроде `mSelectedPositions.valueAt(position);` для получения значения по индексу элемента, но лучше использовать другие типы упорядоченных данных,более простых и с прямым доступом по индексу, так как `Map` здесь излишен.

Answer (score 0):

Решил не заморачиваться(вернее просто осенило) и сделал вручную сдвиг массива при удалении элемента.

```
      public void removeAt(int position) {
        contactList.remove(position);
        mSelectedPositions.delete(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);

        for (int i = position; i < getItemCount() ; i++) {
            mSelectedPositions.put(i, mSelectedPositions.get(i+1));

        }
        notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), contactList.size());
    }
```